# Iterate over an EnumMap which doesn't lead to a new object creation per iteration

Tags: java, keyset, enum-map

Is there a way to iterate over an EnumMap which doesn't lead to a new object creation per iteration? The entryset's iterator returns a new Entry each time. The only way I can see is

```
for(K k: map.keySet()) 
    foo(k, map.get(k));
```

To clarify this is specifically about EnumMap which has the following iterator implementation on its EntrySet

```
 public Map.Entry<K,V> next() {
        if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        lastReturnedEntry = new Entry(index++);
        return lastReturnedEntry;
    }
```

Comment: And what's so bad about your own solution?

Comment: What about `for (V value : map.values()) foo(value);`?  It doesn’t seem like you’re using the keys for anything other than retrieving the values.

Comment: @VGR fair point. I do need the key too.

Comment: In that case you're out of luck. You can write your own EnumMap implementation that does it, although if you need something to return both key and value, but without creating a new object, your solution will definitely not be idiomatic.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yea my current approach isn't bad. I was surprised to come across the EnumMap implementation that even in Java 8 doesn't have a good override for foreach. Just confirming my understanding here and checking if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, from what you're saying it seems like you want the iterator to return a tuple of two objects.

In Java the only way to do this is to wrap them in another object. (At the time of writing, that is.) So the iterator has to return an object other than the key and the value. That object has to be created at some point before a call to `next()` returns.

With that constraint in mind there are three plausible paths to take:

1. Create this entry object on `put()`.
2. Create the entry object on the first iteration across  `entrySet()` (but cache it afterwards).
3. Create a new entry object on every iteration of `entrySet()`.

The built-in `EnumMap` went for option 3 for the possible reasons that it is the simplest to implement and that it's the most economic solution if you don't need to iterate through entries. The drawback is that if you need to iterate more than once, you create more objects than any other solution.

Option 1 is just as simple to implement, but there is an obvious overhead every time you add an entry to the map, even if you never intend to access it.

Finally, option 2 involves slightly more code complexity, and a couple of edge cases when you alternate between iteration and adding more elements, but it gives you the best memory profile in theory.

If the memory overhead of multiple iterations is proven to be a problem in your application, you can easily implement option 2, but I doubt the difference will be noticeable in most cases.

P.s.: if you're willing to stray from idiomatic solutions and go into slightly insane territory, you can re-use the same `Map.Entry` instance for all your entries. This will obviously contradict what we expect from a `Map.Entry`, but it offers you the smallest memory allocation overhead and you can get away with it in simple iteration scenarios. Whether you end up with a faster end product is anybody's guess, you need to measure it.

Answer (score 1):

I reflexively doubt the legitimacy of this level of concern over object creation.  But if avoiding object creation is really this critical, you could maintain your own array of enum constants and test `map.contains(...)` for each.  You'd have to test this to see how the performance compares.

Comment: Yes whether object creation is an issue or not isn't the question. I'm looking for an idiomatic way to do this without having to resort to keeping enum arrays around.

Comment: Why do you have to keep enum arrays around?

Comment: @marstran Because there isn't a form of `EnumMap#contains(...)` that takes the constant's `int` ordinal.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code does **not** create an object every time. It only gets a **reference** to an existing object.

Yes, there is a better way:

```
for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    // use entry.getKey() and entry.getValue()
}
```

Or the Java 8 version:

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> {...});
```

Comment: I'm talking very specifically about EnumMap here. The entrySet iterator looks like the following 

public Map.Entry<K,V> next() {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            lastReturnedEntry = new Entry(index++);
            return lastReturnedEntry;
        }